# How can I animate the rotation of a WPF Button in XAML AND in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, rotation

This is my XAML Code, the button is in a Stackpanel. 
This doestn work with rotation! But for example with  `Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"` it works.

```
<Button Content="Button" x:Name="RotateBtn"  Style="{StaticResource rainbow}" >
    <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                        From="1" To="36" Duration="0:0:3" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Other question: How can I get the same animation with C#?

Answer (score 3):

The default `UIElement.RenderTransform` is `Transform.Identity` so your animation fails since it cannot find `RotateTransform`. You'll need to set the `RenderTranform` to `RotateTransform` on your button.

```
    <Button>
        <Button.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform/>
        </Button.RenderTransform>
  ...
      </Button>
```

A quick search will give you examples of how to create storyboards in code. You just create the `EventTrigger` on the button and add the storyboard to it.